# I don't understand a function of phrase and a relative pronoun

Tags: relative-pronouns, functions

I read an article today and didn't understand the structure.
"Facebook has 3 billion users across its portfolio of apps, a massive number that has raised questions by some legal experts, including US lawmakers, about whether Facebook CEO Mark Zuckerberg neutralizes competitive threats by gobbling them up."

The subject is Facebook. What is the function of "a massive number"?  Is "that" a relative pronoun? It seems to me that the structure is "S + V + O + N + that ~." S is subject, V is a verb(has), and "3 billion users~" is O(object).

Thanks

Comment: It (and the relative clause that modifies it) is in apposition to _3 billion users_.

Comment: John Lawler: Have 3 billion users (all of Facebook users) raised questions if it is apposition?

Comment: The subject of the relative clause is _number_, which is coreferential to _3 billion_. The size of the number, as well as the fact that the number represents **people** -- and not, for instance, dollars -- is what has raised the questions. The relative clause is not in apposition -- the noun phrase it is part of, the rest of the sentence, is in apposition.

Comment: The main clause -- a complete sentence -- is _Facebook has 3 billion users across its portfolio of apps_. The rest of the sentence is apposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Facebook has 3 billion users across its portfolio of apps, a massive*
> *number that has raised questions by some legal experts, including US*
> *lawmakers, about whether Facebook CEO Mark Zuckerberg neutralizes*
> *competitive threats by gobbling them up*.

"A massive number" is part of a larger noun phrase that includes the relative clause "that has raised questions by some legal experts ..." functioning as modifier of "number".

"That" is a subordinator introducing the relative clause. The whole noun phrase "a massive number that has raised questions by some legal experts ..." is an ascriptive supplement that has "3 billion users" as its semantic anchor.

Comment: Is "ascriptive supplement" the new CGEL term for "appositive"?

Comment: No! Appositive NPs are specifying, but the noun phrase commencing "a massive number ..." is ascriptive, It cannot be substituted for the whole construction: it would make little sense to say "Facebook has a massive number that has raised questions...", since readers would be left wondering what "a massive number" refers to.